# Saving output from a function.

Tags: r

I am minimizing this function below using the optim function, which works really well. My only problem is that I can't save the W matrix, I am computing inside the function when minimizing. Is there a way to save the W matrix somehow?

```
W<-c()
GMM_1_stage <- function(beta) {for (i in 1:(nrow(gmm_i))){
  gmm_i[i,]=g_beta(i,beta)}
  gmm_N=t(colSums(gmm_i))%*%colSums(gmm_i) 
  W<-solve((1/(nrow(A)/5))*t(gmm_i)%*%gmm_i) 
  return(gmm_N)
}
GMM_1<-optim(beta_MLE,GMM_1_stage)
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign to an object in the global environment (or in a the closest ancestor environment where the variable is defined) using `<<-`.  So, for example, if I wanted to keep track of every value of  `x` during a simple optimization I could do this.

```
xx<-c()
fun<-function(x){
  xx[length(xx)+1]<<-x
  x^2    
}    
optimize(fun,c(-1,1))
xx
## [1] -2.360680e-01  2.360680e-01  5.278640e-01 -2.775558e-17  4.069010e-05
## [6] -4.069010e-05 -2.775558e-17
```

In your case, if you only want the last value of `W` you can replace that line in your code with:

```
W<<-solve((1/(nrow(A)/5))*t(gmm_i)%*%gmm_i)
```

If you want them all, then first set `Wlist<-list()`, and then in your function set

```
Wlist[[length(Wlist)+1]]<<-solve((1/(nrow(A)/5))*t(gmm_i)%*%gmm_i)
```

Comment: @GregSnow What's that?

Comment: @mrip, the fortunes package contains many quotes representing the wit and wisdom collected from various R related sources over the years, reading random fortunes can be enlightening and/or entertaining.  If you install the fortunes package, load it, then run `fortune(174)` it will give a specific fortune (if the parens are empty then it will give a random fortune).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a safer version of @mrip's answer that uses a temporary environment rather than `<<-`:

```
tempenv <- new.env()
tempenv$xx <- c()
fun<-function(x){
  tempenv$xx[ length(tempenv$xx) + 1 ] <-  x
  x^2    
}    
optimize(fun,c(-1,1))
tempenv$xx
```

By using the temporary environment you don't need to worry about accidentally writing over an object in the global environment or `<<-` assigning in an unexpected place.